# C Programming - Fire Process every nth minute

Tags: c, events, struct, timer

I'm working on a large project where I need to monitor the process of a struct every nth minute.

Each instance of the struct may have it's own length of time for the process to do what it's going to do.

For an example, let's say I monitoring a client connection, struct client.

When the client has been instantiated, I would be looking to incorporate a method such as:

```
void add_Client_Monitor (client_t * client, int seconds)
```

The add_Client_Monitor should then be able to create a timer event that would fire after the seconds stipulated, and also act on the client struct, i.e. by such a method like:

```
void timer_Update_Client(client_t * client)
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use pthreads to create a [timer](http://forums.devshed.com/programming-42/using-pthread-create-stopwatch-timer-592599.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a thread pool for that(like these one github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool or these one github.com/mbrossard/threadpool).
In your add_Client_Monitor function, you could pass a job to a thread pool with the specific function you want to run.
As a simple example:

```
#include "thpool.h"

typedef struct monitor_func_args {
    client_t* client;
    int seconds;
} monitor_func_args;

void* client_monitor_func(void* args){
    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = ((monitor_func_args*) args)->seconds;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    while(1) {
        // Do your stuff
        select (0 ,NULL, NULL, NULL, &timeout); // "sleep" 
    }
}

void add_client_monitor (threadpool pool, client_t * client, int seconds)   {
    monitor_func_args* args = (monitor_func_args*) malloc(sizeof(monitor_func_args));
    args->client = client;
    args->seconds = seconds;
    thpool_add_work(pool, client_monitor_func, (void*) args);
}


int main(){
    threadpool thpool = thpool_init(10); // pool with 10 threads

    client_t* client; // get it from somewhere
    int timeout // get it from somewhere

    add_client_monitor(thpool, &client, timeout) 

    thpool_destroy(thpool);
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't looked at the entire code of these thread pool implementations, but they seem correct.
And of course there are many others that you can use.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help. So in essence, it's not a case of creating a timer itself, but starting a thread that will fire another function, and within that function you can tell it to go to sleep.

Comment: One final question, I could possibly have thousands of these threads running at the same time. What pool size should I set? The server has 12 cores. The threads themselves monitor a clients audio connection and inject a 30second advert every nth minute. The threads will probably be idle for 95% of the time, but individually busy at different times

Comment: That depenends on how many at max can be needed.
Linux has a number of max threads that can be spawned by each process
If they are so many, maybe you should try another solution.
I) Store on a database (like redis or some other with fast read)
and use the threads to pull information from it.
II) Use a CRON to do the jobs

Of course that there are many other solutions depending on the host OS of the application and the database you are using for it

Comment: We're talking about the likes of 50,000 - 100,000